# Java8 fetch data and save in hashmap, performance problem

Tags: java-8, parallel-processing, concurrenthashmap

I have a list of 637200 of rollids, which I use to loop over and get them from a dynamodb table and try to store it in hashmap. I am trying to add this into a custom `ForkJoinPool` of around 8 `Threads`

```
HashMap<String, List<Details>> studentRecord = new HashMap<>();
        rollIds.parallelStream(id -> {
            Details d = fetchDataStudentDao.getStudentById(id);
            studentRecord.put(id, d);
        });
```

**Note: I have no control over `getStudentById` as it comes from some other package which I am not supposed to change.**

I am facing problems using parallel streams, because mapping does not happen correctly. Student with one `id` gets mapped to some other student details.

While checking more on this, I found that `HashMap` are not thread safe and should not be used instead we use `concurrentHashMap` or use forEach.

If I use forEach, it takes more than 4 hours to get the result. but if I use parallelStreams it takes around 3 hours slightly faster than forEach but result are not correct.

Problems which I face, which solution should I use? I am not sure how to use `ConcurrentHashmap` in this case and will it be faster?

Or any other way it can be made faster, some help and guidance immensely required.

Answer (score 0):

Your put(id,d) only puts a single detail, not a list of details.

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead

```
Map<String, Details> studentRecords = rollIds.parallelStream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Functions.identity(), id -> fetchDataStudentDao.getStudentById(id)));
```